# $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( a\binom{k}{1}+b\binom{k+1}{2})=\binom{n+1}{2} \cdot \frac{4n+11}{6}, n\in\ \mathbb{N}, a,b=?, a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: combinatorics

Find $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ knowing:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} ( a\binom{k}{1}+b\binom{k+1}{2})=\binom{n+1}{2} \cdot \frac{4n+11}{6}, n\in\ \mathbb{N}$$
I tried to solve it:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} ( a\binom{k}{1}+b \cdot \frac{k+1}{2}\binom{k}{1})=\binom{n+1}{2} \cdot \frac{4n+11}{6} $$

$$a(\binom{1}{1}+\binom{2}{1}+\cdots \binom{n}{1}) + b(\frac{2}{2}\binom{1}{1} +\frac{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}+\frac{4}{2}\binom{3}{1}+ \cdots + \frac{n+1}{2}\binom{n}{1}) =\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \frac{4n+11}{6}  $$

$$\frac{an(n+1)}{2}+\frac{b}{2}\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \frac{4n+11}{6} $$
$$\dots$$

$$6a+2bn+4b=4n+11$$
I'm not very sure that this approach is correct:
$$2bn=4n \implies b=2 \text{ and }a=\frac{1}{2}$$
Did I approach wrong the exercise?
Thank you!

Comment: seems fine to me

Comment: My dilemma, it is ok in this situation to equalize the coefficients of n in the same way as complex numbers or radicals?

Comment: There doesn't seem any other way to do this question,at least to me

Comment: Yes, I equalized the coefficients because I didn't know another method to find a and b...

Comment: It seems that it is the only way. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The reason for equalizing the coefficients of n is that you've got a polynomial : $(2b-4)x+6a+4b-11$ which vanishes for an infinity of values (all the integers) thus it must be the zero polynomial so all its coefficients are zero.

Comment: Yes, You're right, I didn't think that way!

Comment: An alternative approach is to note that this is an infinite system of linear equations. Since there are only two unknowns, we only need two (independent) equations. Choosing $n=1,2$, for example, yields $a+b=15/6$ and $3a+4b=19/2$.